# why maximize likelihood, rather than maximizing the inverse of the likelihood?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

Let $X$ be a vector of sample data, and $W$ is a vector of parameters of a model based on that data, and we want to estimate a vector $W^*$ that is, informally speaking, "as close to $W$ as possible".

Then shouldn't we maximize $P(W^*|X)$? that is, we should choose the parameter estimates W* such that the probability that they are the actual parameters, is maximized.

Why then, in maximum likelihood, do we want to maximize $P(X|W^*)$ instead? I don't see the (intuitive) justification behind it.

(On a more general note, I also don't see why $P(X|W^*)$ is called "likelihood of $W^*$, given $X$", since "likelihood" and "probability" seem to me to be synonymous in the original meanings of the words).

Comment: Does this help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224037/wikipedia-entry-on-likelihood-seems-ambiguous/224299#224299 ? TLDR; W is not a random variable, it does not have distribution, so we do not have conditional distribution for it unless you are willing to assume that it is a random variable and it has a distribution, but then you are a Bayesian.

Comment: Just to be clear: does TLDR refer to my question or to the post you referred to?
In any case, the post kind of skipped over the thing that I don't understand, namely why maximizing P(X|W*) is sufficient to give a correct estimate of W. Even if you are a frequentist, what is the justification of this?

Comment: Does this help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms ?

Comment: Actually it helps in the sense that one of the answers more clearly states my intuition: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112547/127096.

maximizing the likelihood is in the end not what we want, since we want the W* that has the highest probability of being close to the actual W. So therefore, I don't see the justification of maximizing the likelihood, if what we want is a correct estimate of the parameters W.

Comment: Please explain to us how you would calculate P(W*|X) without invoking additional assumptions such as a prior distribution for W.

Comment: no, of course you would have to invoke additional assumptions. I don't see how that justifies maximizing the likelihood, so my question stands.

Comment: *Likelihood* & *probability* are not synonyms. See: [Can a probability distribution value exceeding 1 be OK?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4220/7290) & [What is the difference between “likelihood” and “probability”?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2641/7290)

Comment: If I understand @programmer2134 correctly, this all really boils down to "if you're a frequentist, why not be a Bayesian instead". That doesn't seem to exactly duplicate anything suggested so far but I'm not sure how "answerable" that is. The best way I can see this question being "answered" is to restate Tim's first comment (if you're a frequentist, then W doesn't even have a distribution, so maximising P(W|X) is meaningless) and to perhaps to pick up on a few of the other misconceptions (eg as gung has done, when used as terms of art "probability" and "likelihood" are not synonyms)

Comment: I still don't think that would persuasively address the concerns raised in this question, but perhaps @programmer2134 should read up about the Bayesian/Frequentist debate to understand at least why P(W|X) can be meaningful in one paradigm and meaningless in another.

Comment: @silverfish, I understand why P(W|X) is meaningless in the frequentist paradigm. So you COULD interpret my question as "why the heck would you be a frequentist". However, I would formulate it differently, namely: How could one justify maximizing likelihood? Surely, frequentists have a justification for this, right? Perhaps my question boils down to: "How would a frequentist justify drawing conclusions about w from maximizing p(x|w)?"

Comment: @Programmer2134: It might help to incorporate your last comment into your question. Answers might cover some of the following: (1) the direct appeal to likelihood as a measure of support (Royall, Edwards, Hacking),  (2) its relation to information theory (see Kullback-Liebler divergence), & (3) its utility in constructing tests/intervals/estimates with good, sometimes optimal, frequentist properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Likelihood" and "probability" in their colloquial usage are synonyms, but in statistics they have different meanings.

Let's start with defining our setting. We observed some independent and identically distributed datapoints $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and we have some model for this data that can be defined in terms of probability distribution $f$ parametrized by some unknown parameter $\theta$. Function $f_\theta(x_i)$ tells us about probability (or [density](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok)) of observing $x_i$ value given some parameter value $\theta$.

Usually we calculate probabilities to check how probable is some $x$ given the distribution $f_\theta$ (e.g. what is the probability of obtaining $x$ points on some test knowing that the distribution of test scores is $f_\theta$). In case of likelihood function, we use it other way around and think about $f_\theta$ *as of a loss function* that returns higher values for $x$'s that better fit the distribution $f_\theta$ and lower values for $x$'s that are unlikely given this distribution.

To gain some more intuition, look at the plot below. It shows three probability density functions **A**, **B** and **C** and datapoints marked as red [rug plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126591/what-is-the-name-of-this-plot-using-vertical-lines-to-show-a-distribution/126593#126593) below the main plot. As you can see, in case of distribution **A** only a single point falls into highest density region, so this does not seem to be a good model. More points fall into highest density regions of functions **B** and **C**, but since **B** catches majority of points in it's highest density region, we can conclude that it fits the data better. This is very informal way of showing how likelihood works.

[image: Different probability density functions against datapoints]

More formally, likelihood function as a function of data given some fixed parameter that calculates total fit of $f_\theta$ across all the points

$$ \mathcal{L}(\theta|X) = P(X|\theta)  = \prod_i f_\theta(x_i) $$

We call it *likelihood* since we do not care about actual probabilities and use the $f_\theta$ functions simply as loss functions. Second, in non-Bayesian setting $\theta$ is *not* a random variable, so we cannot compute $P(\theta|X)$, the *direct* answer for our question, so instead we use likelihood as a proxy.

Moreover, if we become Bayesians for a while and assume that $\theta$ is a random variable that follows [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (suppose this is the range of values that $\theta$ can take), then Bayes theorem [reduces to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214398/bayes-optimal-classifier-vs-likelihood-ratio/214488#214488) calculating likelihood

$$ P(\theta|X) \propto P(X|\theta) P(\theta) = P(X|\theta) \times \text{const} \propto P(X|\theta)$$

and this is the same as maximizing the likelihood function over whole range of possible values of parameter

$$ \underset{\theta\in\Theta}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} ~ \mathcal{L}(X; \theta) $$

so it does not really make that much difference.

Check also:
[Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) in layman terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms)
[What is the difference between "likelihood" and "probability"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability)
[Wikipedia entry on likelihood seems ambiguous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224037/wikipedia-entry-on-likelihood-seems-ambiguous)

Comment: The last 3 lines I think answer my question. However, why do you assume that P(theta) = const?

Comment: @Programmer2134 because we assumed uniform distribution, so for *every* value from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ it returns *the same* probability density.

Comment: right, I understand, but why is this the assumption, since in by far most practical applications this does not apply, right? Or do frequentists acknowledge that maximizing likelihood only has relevance if we know little to nothing about the prior distribution of our parameters?

Comment: @Programmer2134 in non-Bayesian settings there is no priors, so we do not assume a priori that any value of parameter is more likely than other. This example simply translates the frequentest setting to Bayesian perspective to show "what would happen" **if** in frequentist case we actually could compute $P(\theta|X)$. If we could, then it would not make any difference. And while we are talking about frequentist setting, there is no such a thing as a priori assumptions about parameters.